# react-dropzone: isDragReject is true when accept csv?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

```js
const {
  acceptedFiles,
  getRootProps,
  getInputProps,
  isDragActive,
  isDragAccept,
  isDragReject,
} = useDropzone({
  accept: ".csv",
});
console.log(isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject)
```

When dragging a csv file, this code logs "true, false, true". But `react-dropzone` accepted the csv file.

I tried with images and all worked as expected.

I also tries `accept: ".csv, text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/csv, text/x-csv, application/x-csv, text/comma-separated-values, text/x-comma-separated-values"`, not working.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/171#issue-154104200) maybe related, but it's closed without a solution.

I'm using `isDragActive`, `isDragAccept` and `isDragReject` to style the components.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-accepting-specific-file-types, with `useDropzone`, you have to use MIME types as the key. I used the below and it worked well for me.

```
accept: {
      'text/csv': [
        '.csv, text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/csv, text/x-csv, application/x-csv, text/comma-separated-values, text/x-comma-separated-values',
      ],
    },
```